# Subdividing structured abstracts

Tags: sectioning, sections-paragraphs, abstract

I am trying to produce a structured abstract, i.e. with subdivisions. For that purpose, the `\paragraph` command would produce the perfect output since I would like no line break after the subtitle of the abstract, but it seems not to work directly in the `abstract` environment (without being under `\section`). An empty `\section` could solve the problem, but produces a lot of white space. Does any of you have s solution to this problem?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract} 
\section*{}
\paragraph*{Lorem}
\blindtext[1]
\paragraph*{Ipsum}
\blindtext[1]

\end{abstract} 

\end{document}
```

This produces too much space between the abstract title and the text body. Without `\section, however, the document will not compile. Are there any ghost sections?

Comment: Or could one as a solution use a command for once removing the line break after \subsubsection?

Answer (score 7):

I suggest *not* using `\paragraph`, but a custom made command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newcommand{\absdiv}[1]{%
  \par\addvspace{.5\baselineskip}% adjust to suit
  \noindent\textbf{#1}\quad\ignorespaces
}

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
\absdiv{Lorem}
\blindtext[1]
\absdiv{Ipsum}
\blindtext[1]

\end{abstract}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are cleaner ways to do this that do not abuse the syntax of `\paragraph` and would make things work in a TOC, if you have one. That said a simple solution is to add a blank line with `\hspace{0pt}` and then remove some of the vertical space. You can replace your section command with `\hspace{0pt}\vspace{-2\baselineskip}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract} 
\hspace{0pt}\vspace{-2\baselineskip}
\paragraph*{Lorem}
\blindtext[1]
\paragraph*{Ipsum}
\blindtext[1]

\end{abstract} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! Of course, I have no use of the \paragraph per se, but wanted to use it of an example of the desired layout.