# How to remove a blank page "before" the title page

Tags: titles, blank-page

I'm using MiKTeX 2.9 and TeXniCenter for writing my thesis. I have a lot of packages and everything was going well, until last night that a blank page with ".0" written in the top left corner kept generating *before* my title page and still I cannot figure out how to remove it. Is there any kind of command that I can use except `\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage`?

I have been searching heavily but could not find a useful way. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: What did you change, before this appeared? Can you post a MWE which shows this behaviour?

Comment: @Michael I only added the appendix section which I don't think have anything to do with the blank page. Actually, I'm using a template for it and have not seen anyone facing such an issue. Regarding MWE, I don't think I'm able to do that!

Comment: Btw, one more thing is that I'm not using \thanks in \author (there's only one author), so it's not about it if someone is thinking so.

Comment: *Something* changed. But without more information, this seems like a very open-ended question. You should start by stripping away things you may have changed in the last couple of days to try and narrow down the problem. For example, remove any reference to the appendix (file) and recompile. If that still shows a problem, remove all the chapters except for the title content, and so forth...

Comment: @Werner Yes, I think ultimately I have to do this. Out of curiosity, is there a way to remove a page from a pdf file?

Comment: @ehsanmo: Yes, you can discard it using [`atbegshi`](http://ctan.org/pkg/atbegshi)'s `\AtBeginShipoutDiscard`. I've done something similar in [Compiling only a page range or page selection](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/96256/5764). The [`pagesel` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/pagesel) can also help in that regard.

Comment: Such a thing can happen if a counter is erroneously assigned a value with a decimal point. Something like `\setcounter{page}{1.0}`. This could happen in your own file or be a bug in some package. In the latter case it would likely also generate an error message.

Comment: Do you get a "Missing begin document" error message?  That would indicate an error in one of the \usepackage files.

Comment: @JohnKormylo No, I'm not getting such a message. Tnx btw

Comment: @Werner Thank you for your help. I've used your code, but I do not know what number should I write in \discardpages{?} because the blank page is before the title page I assumed number zero should work, but it didn't. Number one discarded the title page though!

Comment: @Dan Thanks, but there's no such a thing in my \setcounter.

Comment: @ehsanmo: I didn't say there was an erroneous `\setcounter` in your file, or even that it was necessarily in a `\setcounter` command. A lot of counter settings are done by other commands.   You really can provide a MWE: You start by reducing to just the title page. Then you remove packages and `\newcommand`s one at a time until that blank page disappears. Put back the last thing you removed and start removing more. Eventually you'll have your MWE.

Comment: @Werner, that simply worked, thank you for saving my life :)

Comment: Although we don't have a MWE here; but the cause of the problem could be something like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161876/thanks-in-ieeetran-adds-an-extra-page/161878#161878).

Comment: I had a similar issue and found that it was because I was using \paragraph in my abstract. Resolved very neatly using suggestion here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74371/subdividing-structured-abstracts

Comment: Future visitors of this page might find the more direct question useful:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161876/thanks-in-ieeetran-adds-an-extra-page?noredirect=1&lq=1
I've put the \thanks outside the \author command.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

For what it's worth or if all else fails, you can *always* remove the first page by adding the following to your document preamble:

```
\usepackage{atbegshi}% http://ctan.org/pkg/atbegshi
\AtBeginDocument{\AtBeginShipoutNext{\AtBeginShipoutDiscard}}
```

This should affect only the next shipout at the document start, which defaults to the first page.

Comment: Actually this solution in my experience works, but as a side effect it removes the index in PDF documents. I'm using LyX on Windows and the output is generated using XeTeX.

Comment: Using this atbegshi package also removes \pagecolor setting

Comment: wow this was really helpful!

Comment: That makes the first page numbered page 2.

Comment: @Geremia: You can add `\addtocounter{page}{-1}` to the `\AtBeginDocument` content.

Comment: Solution by @Geremia is correct. the syntax is                            
\AtBeginDocument{\AtBeginShipoutNext{\AtBeginShipoutDiscard}\addtocounter{page}{-1}}

Comment: Beautifully hacky!

Answer (score 31):

Instead of chucking out the problem page, you should avoid generating it in the first place.

You're getting an extra page because *something* is producing output before `\maketitle`. You can even see the output: `.0`, as you report. So, my guess is that somewhere in your header you're assigning a decimal number to a counter that only accepts integers: E.g., `10.0` instead of just `10`. The leftovers are treated as text, and printed on the first page. Examine your compilation messages (or .log file if necessary), and you should be able to spot the error. (If the error is ahead of `\begin{document}`, you'll get a very obvious complaint about that.)

If you have no such assignment in your preamble, then it's hidden in one of the packages you include. How could this happen? Most likely, one package redefines a command that another package then (mis)uses. A bit of experimenting should discover the two culprits. You can often avoid such problems by simply reversing their order of inclusion.

Comment: Moving \begin{flushleft} from before to after \maketitle fixed the problem for me. I only found out by trial and error. There was no warning or error stating that \begin{flushleft} was the problem.

Answer (score 4):

I just discovered the following. Two blank pages before the title were generated when I tried to put blank lines (`\ \\`) between `\author{}` and `\date{}` commands.
Namely, the following code generated the extra blank pages:

```
\title{title}

\author{name}
\ \\
\ \\
\date{year}

\maketitle
```

and this one did not:

```
\title{title}

\author{name}
\date{year}

\maketitle
```

Comment: Those lines are indeed useless. You should *never* have those in a document.

Answer (score 2):

I keep on generating the numbered blank front page upon adding a one-page pdf as external material that served as the document's cover page. I was able to remove the blank front page when I added an even number of pdf pages, indicating the addition of two pages in the options tab with the command:

```
pages={1-2}
```

I am using the Tufte template, with two-sided document setting. Adding an odd-numbered appendix would have caused the blank front page.

Answer (score 1):

Try clear all temporary files, then recompile your .Tex file.

Comment: What do you mean by temporary files?

Comment: @ehsanmo: See [File extensions of LaTeX-related files](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7770/5764) and/or [Egad! What are all those files?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53240/5764)

Comment: When you compile the TEX file are generated some files like (.aux, .blg, .ilg, .dvi, .log, .out, ...).
Open TeXWorks, click ``"File | Remove Auxiliary Files..."`` and click on Delete button.

Answer (score 1):

Also consider `.tex` file encoding and line endings. Especially if developing goes under different platforms. For example, I solved similar problem just re-saving `.tex` file with UTF-8 encoding.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by writing

```
\begin{titlepage}

\title {My title plus the footnotes}
```

i.e. I put inside the brackets title plus footnotes and it worked!

Comment: If there is a `titlepage` enviroment, `\title` should not be used.

Answer (score -2):

Use either `titlepage` or `\maketitle` but not both.

Comment: This is more a kind of comment. Can you at least explain, whats the problem with using both and show how removing either `titlepage` or `\maketitle` can help. And please have a look into our [Help Center](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help), e.g., to learn how to use markdown and how to write good answers.

Answer (score -2):

If you found symbol `~` in LaTeX file before or after `\title`, please remove it because it generate blank page before title page