# \thanks in IEEEtran adds an extra page

Tags: ieeetran

When I use "\thanks" in IEEEtran, an extra page including a "1" at the top left corner appears before the first page. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[english]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\title{Title Title Title Title Title}
\author{Author Author Author Author Author}
\thanks{This work was supported in part by NSF.}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should put `\thanks` inside `\author` which is the proper way of using it:

```
\documentclass[english]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\title{Title Title Title Title Title}
\author{Author Author Author Author Author\thanks{This work was supported in part by NSF.}}

\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Salman Glad it helped. :)